# What does this terminology mean in this introduction to likelihood ratios?

Tags: terminology, likelihood, likelihood-ratio, jacobian

I am currently reading In All Likelihood by Yudi Pawitan (2013 edition) and I am making my way through the second chapter on the likelihood function. In part 2.4 which is where likelihood functions are first introduced it reads

> How should we compare the likelihood of different values of a parameter, say $L(\theta_1)$ verses $L(\theta_2)$? Suppose $y$ is a one-to-one transformation of the observed data $x$; if $x$ is continuous, $$p_\theta(y) = p_\theta(x(y)) \left| \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right|$$

I am a little confused by this, it looks like it's something along the lines of chain rule but I couldn't fill in the details. I also don't see why you would want to take the absolute value of the partial derivatives at any point?

Can anyone help me realise what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This is from the change of variable-formula for (multiple) integrals. That strange extra factor $\left| \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right|$ is the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

The formula says that the elementary probability in a small volume is conserved: $p(y) \ \delta y = p(x(y)) \ \delta x$.  This leads to your equation.  The absolute values are there since the probability density has to be positive.  Note that the likelihood function is not a density and does not transform this way.